# Use function eval( )+ function find()

Tags: matlab, find, eval

%%%%%%%%%%%%%  2 - Old %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I modified the code as suggested by achieve greater efficiency. I have new errors in the code, not being an expert of access to the cell array

```
for i = first:N_Files 

  mat{i} = load(files(i).name); 

    A{i} = mat{1,i}; 
    x{i} = A{:,i}; 
    ind{i} = find(x{i}>= -0.5 & x{i}<=0.5);

% New error

    B{i} = A{ind{i,:},:}; **Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**
    xx{i} = B(:,1);

end
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%  1 - Old %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I wrote a routine to access files placed in different folders.
Then build a cell array where are stored file data with the routine:

```
for i = first:N_Files 
    mat{i} = load(files(i).name); % 1x3 cell
   eval(['A' num2str(i) '= mat{1,i} ;']) % A1,A2,A3 dim : 114336x6 double
end

A = {A1, A2, A3}; cell array 1x3
```

I have a problem of access to some vectors created on the evaluation of a matrix cell.

```
    for i = first:N_Files

      eval(['x' num2str(i) '= A{:,i} ;']) % create x1, x2, x3
```

> > % incorrect code
> >
> > eval(['ind' num2str(i) '= find('x' num2str(i) >= -0.5 & 'x' num2str(i)
> >     <=0.5) ;'])

```
   end
```

> % need this indexing  solution

```
ind1 = find(x1>= -0.5 & x1<=0.5);
ind2 = find(x2>= -0.5 & x2<=0.5);
ind3 = find(x3>= -0.5 & x3<=0.5);
```

I necessity to have the eval function with the find function, 
it's possible?
have a useful solution?
thanks

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Complete Code %%%%%%

This is the code that I had to get.

```
    for i = first:N_Files 

        A{i} = load(files(i).name); % 1x3 cell
        x = A{:,1};
        ind{i} = find(x(:,1)>= -0.5 & x(:,1)<=0.5); % This looks cleaner

        B{i} = A{i}(ind{i},:); % Correct,first access element i in A then filter.
        xx{i} = B{i}(:,1); %1x3 cell **what i really wanted**        
        yy{i} = B{i}(:,2); 
        zz{i} = B{i}(:,3); 
        u{i} = B{i}(:,4); % vettore velocità
        v{i} = B{i}(:,5);
        w{i} = B{i}(:,6);
        c1{i} = [-0.5:0.01:0.5];
        c2{i} = [0:0.01:2] ;

        [X{i},Z{i}] = meshgrid(c1{i},c2{i});

        U{i} = griddata(xx{i},zz{i},u{i},X{i},Z{i});
         U{i}(isnan(U{i}))=0;  % interpolazione ai bordi
         W{i} = griddata(xx{i},zz{i},w{i},X{i},Z{i});
          W{i}(isnan(W{i}))=0;

          figure
    pcolor(X{i},Z{i},(U{i}.^2+W{i}.^2).^0.5);
    shading(gca,'interp')
    title('Velocità')
    colorbar;
    axis square
    hh = streamslice(X{i},Z{i},U{i},W{i});

    set(hh,'color','k');

    end
```

Comment: Avoid `eval`. You can use cells like this: `A{i} = mat{1,i}` or this `x{i} = A{:,i}` instead.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to take @knedlsepp 's advice, as it is much better practice compared to using eval. Also from the code provided x=A essentialy. Why not use A directly?

Comment: @knedlsepp  thanks for solution is very good. and if i need to access of new matrix with index ?  B{i} = A{ind{i,:},:}; ???? have error Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: @brodroll Do not use A for now because I'm writing the raw code. conclude and when I check on the general operation, I try to improve the code.
I keep learning I do not understand, the -1 that was assigned to me

Comment: @Antonio You can preallocate the cell (`ind = cell(mySize)`), or build it up step by step (`ind = [ind,{nextInd}]`). When you call `ind` then, you write `ind{2}` instead of `ind2`,...

Comment: sorry @patrik don't understand answer. i need B{i} = A{ind(:,i),:};  I necessity to work with indexes in the cell array, I have to process many files and cell arrays me allows me to synthesize the code. ithis is the first approach to this type of code and am finding difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will try to help you as good as I can. First, if you have a cell that have the dimension 1xN, you do only need one index: `A{i} = mat{i}`. However, you then see that `A==mat`, which means that both are not needed. On the next row, you do `x{i} = A{:,i}` which seems to be the same as you do on the former row => `x==mat`. This means that we can remove two rows. Then I guess that your goal is to find the indices which have an absolute value smaller than 0.5 for each file and store each in a cell, right? Then to the error: By doing `A{ind{i,:},:}` you are actually sub-referencing `A` itself and not each element of `A`. The size of `A` is 1*nFiles. What you are trying to do is indeed this: `B{i} = A{i}(ind{i})`.

So if this is not what you want please comment. Otherwise, remove redundant variables. **And make sure that you do not mix up cell with matrix. You use a cell as a container for arrays: a{n} refers to the array in cell element n and a{n}(m) refers to matrix element m in the array located in cell element n.** Good luck!

```
for i = first:N_Files 

    mat{i} = load(files(i).name); 

    %A{i} = mat{1,i}; % not needed mat==x
    %x{i} = A{:,i}; % not needed x==A
    x = mat; % Fix this later, I do not want to change any variable names.

    % ind{i} = find(x{i}>= -0.5 & x{i}<=0.5);
    ind{i} = find(abs(x{i})<=0.5); % This looks cleaner

    %B{i} = A{ind{i,:},:}; **Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**
    B{i} = A{i}(ind{i}); % Correct,first access element i in A then filter.
    xx{i} = B(:,1); %I do not know what you tries to do but probably
                    %xx{i}=B{i} => x==B so one variable is redundant.

end
```

Comment: Excuse me for answering so late.  I'm working on the code,.
Your suggestion has been very helpful, I would say definitively.
where I can enter the solution of the code? thanks @patrik

Comment: @Antonio what do you mean with solution? Matlab code is meant to be run in matlab so you do not need to create a project to run matlab code. Thus I would guess that a folder system where you set the path, using the function `addpath`, have it in your startup.m file, or in pathdef.m, is enough. Then you are good to go. If this is not what you mean with solution, would you mind elaborating a bit on that?

Comment: with "solution code", I mean the final code or complete code

Comment: @Antonio I thought this was the complete code. Except for `xx` maybe, which was kept since I did not know what to do with it. You should yourself check the code and make sure that you use the right one if the redundant variables in the correct place. Since `x == A == mat` it is hard for me to say exactly which one to use. I suggests you one choose one of them and use that everywhere. It should be straight forward.

Comment: I added the full code, I need to create a function for multiple access to folders, and a function to a good layout of figure plot ad subplot.  I think the my writing on StackOverflow is not appreciated. maybe I'm too redundant in writing?

Comment: @Antonio please redo the addition and post a new question. This one have a answer, which was accepted and can thus be considered closed. Adding another topic will make this question messy. Further the rest of the issue seems unrelated, so it would probably fit better in another question anyway. Post a link as a comment here as well. Also try to make the question general, since others may not have read this question before. However, I would guess that you need to do the reading the old school way by listing all the directories and looping through all of them.

Comment: @Antonio Anyway, Stack Overflow is so hateful these days. Just add a new independent question and post a link.